# How to set an GTK Entry as an default active element in Python GTK2

Tags: python, gtk2

How can I set a GTK entry as default activated element / widget on start so I can insert my text without click into the entry widget first?

For example, when I start this script I want to insert into entry2 by default:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
mainbox    = gtk.VBox()
window.add(mainbox)
mainbox.pack_start(gtk.Label("Label 1"))
entry1 = gtk.Entry()
mainbox.pack_start(entry1)
mainbox.pack_start(gtk.Label("Label 2"))
entry2 = gtk.Entry()
mainbox.pack_start(entry2)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

I could not find an option:

- http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkentry.html
- http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkwidget.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found:

**5.10. How do I focus a widget? How do I focus it before its toplevel window is shown?**

http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq05.010.htp&req=show

```
entry2.grab_focus()
```

.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk

window  = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
mainbox = gtk.VBox()
window.add(mainbox)
mainbox.pack_start(gtk.Label("Label 1"))
entry1 = gtk.Entry()
mainbox.pack_start(entry1)
mainbox.pack_start(gtk.Label("Label 2"))
entry2 = gtk.Entry()
mainbox.pack_start(entry2)

entry2.grab_focus()

window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```